# How to convert column to vector type?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I have an RDD in Spark where the objects are based on a case class:

```
ExampleCaseClass(user: User, stuff: Stuff)
```

I want to use Spark's ML pipeline, so I convert this to a Spark data frame. As part of the pipeline, I want to transform one of the columns into a column whose entries are vectors. Since I want the length of that vector to vary with the model, it should be built into the pipeline as part of the feature transformation.

So I attempted to define a Transformer as follows:

```
class MyTransformer extends Transformer {

  val uid = ""
  val num: IntParam = new IntParam(this, "", "")

  def setNum(value: Int): this.type = set(num, value)
  setDefault(num -> 50)

  def transform(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    ...
  }

  def transformSchema(schema: StructType): StructType = {
    val inputFields = schema.fields
    StructType(inputFields :+ StructField("colName", ???, true))
  }

  def copy (extra: ParamMap): Transformer = defaultCopy(extra)

}
```

How do I specify the DataType of the resulting field (i.e. fill in the ???)? It will be a Vector of some simple class (Boolean, Int, Double, etc). It seems VectorUDT might have worked, but that's private to Spark. Since any RDD can be converted to a DataFrame, any case class can be converted to a custom DataType. However I can't figure out how to manually do this conversion, otherwise I could apply it to some simple case class wrapping the vector.

Furthermore, if I specify a vector type for the column, will VectorAssembler correctly process the vector into separate features when I go to fit the model?

Still new to Spark and especially to the ML Pipeline, so appreciate any advice.

Comment: 1) `Vectors` in Spark support only `Double` type (these are not the same as Scala `Vector,` see stackoverflow.com/q/31255756/1560062) 2) [`VectorUDT` is not private](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/Vectors.scala#L192) 3) Not every RDD can converted to a DataFrame or at least not directly and not every case class can be automatically used asd `Dataset` (`Frame`) element.

Comment: And not all `RDD`s can be converted to `DataFrame`s. [Dirty RDD](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6280514/ShareX/2016/03/2016-03-17_21-24-49.png)

Comment: 4) _if I specify a vector type for the column, will VectorAssembler correctly process the vector into separate features_ - if don't understand what the question. Assembler just concatenates columns (and meta if present).

Comment: What I really want to do is create many more columns (not just a long vector in one column) but I couldn't figure out how todo that either without being extremely inefficient. I should only need to run through the data once to create all these columns, and right now I can only see how to do it with a loop.

Comment: That might explain my comment about VectorAssembler, since I really want each element of that vector to be its own feature.

Comment: Do your Vectors have a fixed number of elements, or a different number of elements in the Vectors in each row?

Comment: Same number in each row, but the number is a parameter in the model.

Comment: Despite DataFrame, I think your problem is "how to transform data to Vector"?

Comment: My problem is, given a column whose objects are a highly nested case class, how do I write a Transformer to unroll that into multiple columns with only one pass through the data? The new columns will be extracted programmatically, and the number of columns will be a parameter in the model. The problem is some combination of doing that efficiently and specifying the correct schema types.

Answer (score 6):

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SQLDataTypes.VectorType  
def transformSchema(schema: StructType): StructType = {
  val inputFields = schema.fields
  StructType(inputFields :+ StructField("colName", VectorType, true))
}
```

In spark 2.1 VectorType makes VectorUDT publicly available:

```
package org.apache.spark.ml.linalg

import org.apache.spark.annotation.{DeveloperApi, Since}
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType

/**
 * :: DeveloperApi ::
 * SQL data types for vectors and matrices.
 */
@Since("2.0.0")
@DeveloperApi
object SQLDataTypes {

  /** Data type for [[Vector]]. */
  val VectorType: DataType = new VectorUDT

  /** Data type for [[Matrix]]. */
  val MatrixType: DataType = new MatrixUDT
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}

case class MyVector(vector: Vector)
val vectorDF = Seq(
  MyVector(Vectors.dense(1.0,3.4,4.4)),
  MyVector(Vectors.dense(5.5,6.7))
).toDF

vectorDF.printSchema
root
 |-- vector: vector (nullable = true)

println(vectorDF.schema.fields(0).dataType.prettyJson)
{
  "type" : "udt",
  "class" : "org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT",
  "pyClass" : "pyspark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT",
  "sqlType" : {
    "type" : "struct",
    "fields" : [ {
      "name" : "type",
      "type" : "byte",
      "nullable" : false,
      "metadata" : { }
    }, {
      "name" : "size",
      "type" : "integer",
      "nullable" : true,
      "metadata" : { }
    }, {
      "name" : "indices",
      "type" : {
        "type" : "array",
        "elementType" : "integer",
        "containsNull" : false
      },
      "nullable" : true,
      "metadata" : { }
    }, {
      "name" : "values",
      "type" : {
        "type" : "array",
        "elementType" : "double",
        "containsNull" : false
      },
      "nullable" : true,
      "metadata" : { }
    } ]
  }
}
```